# Mouse and Keyboard suddenly don't work upon login

Tags: keyboard, login, mouse

So everything was fine, I finally got Ubuntu up and running for the first time and I loved it.

There was something in my launcher, the stupid Software Installer attempting to install a package (it was frozen and stuck) and I wanted to get rid of it. So I tried to do an `xkill` on it, and it screwed up my whole launcher and had to restart because I had no idea how to get it back.

Restart, go to login, and my keyboard and mouse cease to function. They work in Windows, in recovery mode, and in a live USB session.

So I'm currently mounted on my drive now, trying to do `sudo-apt update && sudo apt-get upgrade` and for some reason it's all starting to fail. I keep getting multiple failed to fetches & "Temporary failure resolvings. I'm trying to get `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all` to work, because maybe this will fix this whole thing, but I can't.

I severely need help, as Ubuntu won't run. It was working like a dream before I shut down my computer.